# How to correlate session id in request body

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

[[this correlation part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC5aQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxaFH.png)

If any one know how to solve problem. Please send the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to correlate values present in cookies. It can be auto handled by HTTP cookie manager (If you have added that element).

For more guide: Refer the [HTTP Cookie Manager documentation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)

Comment: Thank you so much https://stackoverflow.com/users/6810709/rollno748

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to manually extract the value from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header you will need to switch the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)'s scope to "Response Headers"

[image]

However you might want to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager) instead, it automatically extracts the cookies from the response and adds them to the next request if hostname and path match, cookie is not expired and so on.